# Error uploading CSV with more than 200 entities to DialogFlow entity?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to upload CSV formatted entities as bulk to DialogFlow entity interface.
I am getting the following error:

> Errors in 'drug' entity: The number of synonyms is greater than 200.

Please advise how to upload large amount of entities to DialogFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The way to do this is to upload it in the following format:

```
"item1","item1"
"item2","item2"
"item3","item3"
"item4","item4"
"item5","item5"
"item6","item6"
"item7","item7"
"item8","item8"
```

[image]
[image]